# What is the proper way to save a hasMany relationship in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In EmberJS, I am trying to save a model that has a hasMany relationship in it. I have seen this question asked elsewhere, but usually in relation to persisting the child models at the same time as the parent model.

In my case, the child models are already persisted, I just need to reference them. I have attempted to do this several different ways to no avail. I can't seem to find this clearly documented anywhere and half of the examples I have seem appear out of date.

Here is a jsbin with one attempt.

http://jsbin.com/oNuQIGEF/3/edit?html,js,output

Clicking the button should add a new user to the list with two projects, just like the other two users shown. However, it just adds the user with no projects.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you'll have to persist the parent before adding children to it. The following fixed it:

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function(model) {
      var controller = this;
      this.store.find('project').then(function(projects) {
        var user = controller.store.createRecord('user', {
          name: 'Joe'
        });
        user.save().then(function() {
          user.get('projects').pushObjects(projects);
        });
      });
    }
  },
});
```

Also have a look at the following [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/oNuQIGEF/7/)

Comment: Hmm... I thought I had tried that. I guess I was still doing something wrong. Thanks!